# Change the Value of an existing Laravel Collection key

Tags: laravel-5

I have a Laravel Collection $page in which I am trying to update some values based on a value in another collection. But instead up updating a new element is being added to $page.

[image]

```
    if($page->get('Lang') !== null ){
        $l = $page->get('Lang');

        foreach ($l as $thisLang => $value) {
            if($lang == $thisLang){
               //  this is where I am attempt is overwrite the variable
                $page->Name = $value->Name;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Being fairly new to Laravel I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any code corrections are appreciated.

I have also tried :

```
 $page->update( ["Name" , $value->Name] );
```

but get the error

```
 "Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::update does not exist."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of use `$page->Name` need use `$page['Name']`. 
Corrected code is

```
if($page->get('Lang') !== null ){
    $l = $page->get('Lang');

    foreach ($l as $thisLang => $value) {
        if($lang == $thisLang){
           //  this is where I am attempt is overwrite the variable
            $page['Name'] = $value->Name;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```